# How does my code get a value for my variable? C++

Tags: c++

I'm following this book called *C++ Primer Fifth Edition* and it had this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int currVal = 0;
    int val = 0;
    if (std::cin >> val){
        int cnt = 1;
        while (std::cin >> val){
                if (val == currVal){
                    ++cnt;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times " << std::endl;
                    currVal = val;
                    cnt = 1;
                }


        }
        std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times " << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code tells me how many times a number has occured in the users input.

What I don't quite understand yet is how does the code know what the `currVal` is when I gave it a value of 0 and I haven't told it anything about the current value except in the last `else` statement. My question is does the code run the `else` code first and then runs the `if` statement code? But then the `cnt` wouldn't be able to count anything because it always gets reset to 1 at the end of the `else` statement. I know this is pretty basic but I just can't figure out the answer.

I couldn't find an answer on google nor did it explain it in my book so I thought maybe I could ask it here.

Comment: You could step through these lines of code with your debugger one by one, and check how these values actually change.

Comment: There is currVal = 0 in the second line?

Comment: I'm starting to understand it now but what I was confused about was that I didn't give `currVal` any update about the value and it somehow still knew what the current value was. But I think I understand it better now, I will try going tghtough it with a debugger to understand it better.

Comment: It should be `if (std::cin >> currVal ){`; this code only works, if the first input is a `0`; also initializations of `val` and `currVal` are unnecessary...

Comment: I'm not sure my book said it like that and when I test it it seems to work both ways.

Comment: @Rene-R when I run the program and enter `1` and `2`, it prints `0 occurs 1 times` after I enter the `2` even though no 0 was entered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The first time the if() statement is run, it checks against zero.

currVal will only be updated when the else is executed.